# UPS test Tracking Number

Tags: php, tracking, ups

I have integrated the tracking api and it **works fine** and return the message but the **problem** is when i use those test **tracking numbers** on ups website they turn out be **invalid**.

*Shouldn't these test numbers work on ups website and return same message as returned by api??*

Answer (score 2):

The UPS test tracking numbers only work in the Test Environment. You will only be able to see the events of production tracking numbers in the UPS website.

Best!